Transience of random walk on the natural numbers.
Let $X = (X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sim \text{MC}(\lambda,P)$ be a Markov chain on the natural numbers such that $\forall i\neq 0,\, (p_{i,i+1}=2/3$ and $p_{i,i-1}=1/3)$ and $p_{0,1}=1$ (every other value of $P$ is zero).
That is, a Makrov chain in $\mathbb{N}$ where the probability of moving away from zero is $2/3$, the probability of getting closer to $0$ is $1/3$ and the probability of leaving $0$ is $1$, only being able to move one natural number at a time.
I want to show that this MC is transient, which I intuitively belive to be the case. To this end, I'm trying to prove the equivalent statement
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}p_{0,0}^{(n)}<\infty
\end{equation}
Where $p_{0,0}^{(n)}$ is the probability of starting and ending at $0$ in $n$ steps (i.e., $(P^n)_{0,0}$). However, I'm struggling to find a closed form (or sufficiently close upper bound) for $p_{0,0}^{(n)}$.
I'm open to any suggestions or hints on how to prove the convergence of the stated sum.

@geetha290krm I think I disagree. I imagine you are using the statement "$n$ steps up with probability $2/3$ and $n$ steps down with probability $1/3$", however, this statement is not true: consider the $2n$ step sequence $0,1,0,1,...,0,1,0$ which has probability $(1/3)^n$.

@geetha290krm your first statement still isn't true: $p_{0,0}^{(2)}=\frac{1}{3}$ which is inconsistent with your formula.

You are right. I was thinking of Random Walk on $\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb  N$.

Here are two "elementary" approaches, although I am not sure whether they count toward "introductory theorems".
In this answer, I will write $p = \frac{2}{3}$ for the probability of the chain moving to the right (except at $0$). The reason is two-folds: (1) to simplify the formula, and (2) to generalize to other values of $p$.

Method 1. For $n \geq 1$, consider the probability $q_n$ of the first return to $0$ when the chain has started at $0$. That is,
$$ q_n = \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0, X_{n-1} > 0, \ldots, X_1 > 0 \mid X_0 = 0). $$
This probability is non-zero only when $n = 2k + 2$ for some $k \geq 0$.
Now any path $(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ contributing to this probability can be decomposed into the initial move $0 \to 1$, the subsequent "excursion" of length $2k$ that both starts and ends at $1$ while not hitting $1$, and the final move $1 \to 0$:

Then by invoking the Catalan numbers, we know that there are precisely $C_k = \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}$ such paths, each of which occurring with probability $p^k(1-p)^{k+1}$. So,
\begin{align*}
\rho := \mathbf{P}(X_n \text{ returns to } 0 \mid X_0 = 0)
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q_n
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q_{2k+2} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+1} \binom{2k}{k} p^k(1-p)^{k+1}.
\end{align*}
Now, we can check that $\rho = \frac{1-|2p-1|}{2p}$, and this show that this is strictly less than $1$ for $p = \frac{2}{3}$. Below is the graph of $\rho$ as a function of $p$:


Remark. As a side note, OP's sum can be expressed in terms of $\rho$, with the convention $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p^{(n)}_{0,0} = \frac{1}{1-\rho}. $$


Method 2. We invoke the coupling argument.
Let $(\xi_n)$ be IID RVs with $\mathbf{P}(\xi_n = 1) = p$ and $\mathbf{P}(\xi_n = -1) = 1-p$. We construct two processes $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ as follows:

$X_0 = 0$, and $X_{n+1}$ given $X_n$ is defined via the following formula:
$$ X_{n+1} = \begin{cases} 1, & X_n = 0 \\ X_n + \xi_{n+1}, & X_n > 0 \end{cases} $$
The resulting process $(X_n)$ is a Markov process as in OP.

$Y_0 = 0$, and $Y_{n+1} = Y_n + \xi_{n+1}$. That is, $(Y_n)$ is a SRW on $\mathbb{Z}$


Then by induction, it is easy to prove that $X_n \geq Y_n$ for all $n$. This should be intuitive by construction, and its proof is also an easy exercise. Below is a simulation of these two processes:

Also, it is easy to prove that $Y_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$. From this, you can conclude the transience of $(X_n)$ as well.

The easiest is to use  Foster-Lyapunov criterion for transience (Theorem 2).
For the function $g$ choose $g(x)=\frac1{x+1}$, then the expected drift is
$$
Pg(x)-g(x)\equiv\mathbb{E}(g(X_{n+1}-g(X_n)\mid X_n=x)=\frac{2}{3 \left(x +2\right)}+\frac{1}{3 x}-\frac{1}{x +1}=-\frac{x -2}{3 x \left(x +1\right)(x+2)}\le 0
$$
as long as $x\ge 2$ and at the same time $g(x)\to 0$. Hence the chain is transient.

The chain has a single communicating class, so if it is not transient then it is recurrent and every state is visited with probability one.  So make state zero an absorbing state and let $P$ be the associated (countably infinite) matrix for this absorbing chain.
State $0$ cannot be visited with probability one if $P$ has non-trivial fixed points of a certain kind.  Consider
solutions to $P\mathbf x = \mathbf x$ where $x_i\in (0,1]$.  By inspection $x_0 = 1$ and obviously setting $x_i:= 1$ for all other $i$ will give a trivial solution but we are interested in non-trivial solutions for the following reason. Observe $P\mathbf x=\mathbf x \implies P^n\mathbf x = \mathbf x$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. And let $F_{i,0}^{(n)}$ denote the CDF of being absorbed in state $0$ given a start in state $i$ after $n$ iterations.  Then $F_{i,0}^{(n)} = p_{i,0}^{(n)} \leq p_{i,0}^{(n)}\cdot 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_{i,k}^{(n)}\cdot x_k = \text{row i of }P^n\mathbf x =  x_i$.
And $\lim_{n\to \infty}F_{i,0}^{(n)}\leq x_i$ where the limit exists by monotone convergence.  Thus a fixed point with $x_1 \in (0,1)$ bounds the total probability of being absorbed as $\lt 1$ and this proves the OP's original chain is transient.
We can somewhat informally reason that if the probability of absorption from state 1 is $\pi$ then the probability of absorption from state $k$ is $\pi^k$ and use 'first step analysis' to observe $\pi = \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 + \frac{2}{3}\cdot\pi^2$ which has solutions $\pi \in \big\{1, \frac{1}{2}\big\}$. Thus
$P\mathbf x = \mathbf x$ has a solution $\mathbf x  =\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2^2} \\  \frac{1}{2^3}\\\vdots \end{matrix}\right]$ (verifiable via inspection) so OP's original chain must be transient.

As an aside, the above is actually a martingale argument and the boundedness of $\mathbf x$ implies that the probability of visiting state $0$ given a start in state $i$ is  $F_{i,0}^{(\infty)}=x_i$.  However showing $F_{i,0}^{(\infty)}\leq x_i$ required less machinery and was more than adequate for this problem
